# Can I start vim by a bookmark

Tags: linux, vim

I set a global bookmark using `mA` in the file `A.py`. Currently, I open the file using vi (`vi A.py`) and go to the bookmark. I would like to know could I do them by a command line such as `vi --bookmark A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary commands with the `+<cmd>` argument. In your case:

```
$ vim +normal\'A
```

See `:hel -+c` and `:help :normal`.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the command [`A](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark-motions) from the command-line:

```
vim -c 'normal `A'
```

Please note single quotes and a backtick.